# Cant get ubuntu usb to boot

Tags: partitioning, mount, mint

I recently had Linux Mint installed on my new laptop with windows 8.1.
I had problems booting to Mint so i installed rEFInd and managed to get Windows and L+Mint to boot correctly.

I decided i wanted to install Ubuntu instead of Mint so i deleted the partition with Mint and tried to install Ubuntu but everytime i try to boot ubuntu from my usb it sends me to busybox saying:

mount: mounting dev/loop0 on //filesytem.squashfs ...

I read that it was probably a bad download and redownloaded again, but im still getting the same error.

Comment: What system are you using, also how did you create the live usb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new USB boot using [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) or [LiLiUSB](http://www.linuxliveusb.com), both for Windows. Your USB media is corrupted.

Comment: I was using UUI, after using Unetbootin it worked fine!