Problems installing Ubuntu Studio
I´m new to Linux. I have a Dell Latitude 5580 with Windows 10 and I would like to make it DualBoot with Ubunto Studio.
I downloaded the latest Ubuntu Studio version and made bootable USB Stick to try it out or install.
If I booted from stick, the following menu appears:
Try or Install Ubuntu Studio
Ubuntu Studio (safe graphics)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
My problems:

If I use first option "Try or Install Ubuntu Studio" then my laptop screen stays black - I can´t see anything. Missing some graphic driver or?

So, I thought it´s worth to try the second option: "Ubuntu Studio (safe graphics)" then I face my second problem:

following error message appears:

BusyBox v1.36.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.36.1-6ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter "help" for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs) mount: mounting /dev/loop0 on /standard.squashfs failed: Invalid argument
Can not mount /dev/loop0 (/cdrom/casper/standard.squashfs) on /standard.squashfs
I would be very happy if somebody could help me to write what shoud I do to install Ubuntu Studio as a second operating system to my computer. Or is it impossible at all to install Ubuntu to Dell Latitude 5580?
Thanking You In Advance,
Wandersell

Try to redownload the ISO file or change the USB flash drive or the software used to make a bootable USB flash drive.

see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/433899/1698042

Did you verify ISO download before write to media?  Its quick and saves hours of troubleshooting in case 1 bit of the millions was invalid.... Likewise did you verify the ISO write to media (this I find is where most issues occur) again as checks are fast compared to the troubleshooting.   If I have issues on one box, I usually check it on another.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile  etc
